# XMLHttpRequest/ajax set Content-Type

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I've tried both these things separately:

note: url is a variable containing a https url and jsonString contains a valid json string

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
try{
    request.open("POST", url);
    request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    request.send(jsonString);
} catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

and

```
var options = {
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    data: jsonString,
    accept: "application/json"
};

$.ajax(options)
```

The problem is the system we are posting to requires a header Content-Type with a value "application/json".

With the way things are right now, the method used is POST, the Accept header is "application/json", and the Content-Type defaults to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

In the first example, if `request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')`; is added 1 line above or below the Accept header, the method used changes to OPTIONS, the Accept header changes to **"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"** and the **Content-Type** header disappears as if it wasn't seen.

In the second example, if **contentType: "application/json"** is added anywhere within options, the same thing happens that happened in the first example.

What is the proper way to set a Content-Type header in ajax or XMLHttpRequest?

**Edit:** I should add that using the firefox rest client plugin, the json string, url, and accept and content type headers all work fine. We just can't seem to get the content header set on our own page.

Comment: Have a jsfiddle example? Never used the XMLHttpRequest object before but setting the contentType setting to "application/json" should work for jquery. I also don't think there's an "accept" setting. Also, a OPTIONS preflight request occurs when doing a cross domain call. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: I mean, an OPTIONS preflight occurs when doing a cross domain call with a content-type value other than than the default "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" with JQuery.ajax()

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> In the first example, if request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); is added 1 line above or below the Accept header, the method used changes to OPTIONS

This is because you are making [a *cross origin* request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com/35553666#35553666) from JS embedded in a webpage. Changing the `content-type` (to one that you couldn't make with a simple HTML form) triggers [a preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) asking permission from the server to make the actual request.

You need to set up the server to respond with appropriate CORS headers to grant permission.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2008 01:15:39 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your.site.example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Then the browser will make the POST request you are asking it to make.

Comment: why doesn't the firefox rest client plugin fire a cross origin request? or if it does, why is it able to go through without a problem?

Comment: @backcab — Because it is installed software and not a bit of JavaScript from an untrusted website.